# After a fresh upgrade to Windows 10, should I run a tool to scan for outdated drivers, even if I don't have issues?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, upgrade

During my attempts to upgrade to Windows 10, I completely reinstalled Windows 7 first because of issues with my system reserved partition after upgrading to an SSD. After reinstalling Windows 7 to fix the partition, I upgraded to Windows 10 without any real issues and have been using it without problems for about a month now.

currently, I'm not having any issues with Windows 10 or any programs, including drivers, but since most parts in this machine are around 5 years old, I'm not sure whether the relevant driver updates would be delivered through Windows 10 or need to be done manually, or even whether there are Windows 10 compatible drivers yet.

Now, the advice that's usually recommended concerning tools that scan for outdated drivers is "don't use them, they're risky", and the advice for updating non-GPU drivers is "if you're not having issues, don't bother since it likely won't improve things and may even break things". Does this advice still hold if you recently upgraded your OS and may have outdated drivers?

Comment: If there are updates then install them.  There is no single answer to this question.  Why do you need a tool to find device drivers?

Comment: 1) I would just do the updates myself.
2) I would do the updates even if everything looks fine. There may be an issue you do not see now but may encounter later, and it might not seem like a driver problem.

Comment: re: your last paragraph -- still good advice.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  If you decide to update drivers anyway, do it manually rather than using a driver update utility, and get the OEM drivers from the computer manufacturer's web site rather than "retail" drivers from the chipset manufacturer's web site.

Comment: @fixer1234 I would not use it to update the drivers, I'd use it to check for outdated drivers, then update those drivers manually, as you recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this advice still hold if you recently upgraded your OS and may have outdated drivers?

It holds even more strongly, since you are far less likely to have outdated drivers when all your drivers were up to date only three weeks ago.

Comment: I don't know if everything was up to date 3 weeks ago. First of all, I installed Windows 7 from a 2-3 year old ISO because it was an OEM, so it didn't come with the most recent drivers. Secondly, I'm not sure whether Windows 10 automatically updates ALL drivers, or just a select few, so installing Windows 10 shouldn't automatically mean all drivers are updated.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't *update* any drivers. It discards all previous drivers and installs its own.